# Firefox event firing issue

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a list in markup with a connected event listener, each li contains one or two divs and the idea is to do some stuff depending on what div was clicked.
HTML sample:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li><div class="first a"></div><div class="second b c"></div></li>
    <li><div class="first f"></div></li>
    <li><div class="first e"></div><div class="second d r"></div></li>
…
```

JS sample:

```
var currentLang = 'en';
var failCounter = 0;
var currentArg = args[Math.floor(Math.random() * args.length)];
var previousArgs = [];

function keyClicked(event) {
    if (event.target.className.split(' ').indexOf(currentArg) > -1) {
        textBox.style.opacity = 0;
        setTimeout(function () {
            textBox.innerHTML = wonMessages[currentLang];
            textBox.style.opacity = 1;
            wrapper.className = 'alert alert-success wrapper-active';
        }, 250);
        wrapper.onclick = function () { location.href = "…" };
        list.removeEventListener('click', keyClicked);
    }
    else {
        if (failCounter < 1) {
            failCounter++;
            previousArgs.push(currentArg);
            do { currentArg = args[Math.floor(Math.random() * args.length)]; }
            while (previousArgs.indexOf(currentArg) > -1);
            textBox.style.opacity = 0;
            setTimeout(function () {
                textBox.innerHTML = wrongMessages[currentLang];
                textBox.style.opacity = 1;
                wrapper.className = 'alert alert-warning';
            }, 250);
        }
        else {
            textBox.style.opacity = 0;
            setTimeout(function () {
                textBox.innerHTML = lostMessages[currentLang];
                textBox.style.opacity = 1;
                wrapper.className = 'alert alert-danger';
            }, 250);               
            list.removeEventListener('click', keyClicked);
        }
    }
}
list.addEventListener('click', keyClicked);
```

The problem is that while it works fine in IE and Chrome, Firefox for some reason doesn't fire an event when a div of class `first` (the first one or the only one in `li` if `li` contains only one div) is clicked. Firefox recognizes only clicks on divs of class `second`.
Any ideas, why? What difference between those browser leads to that?

Comment: it's time to wait for a jquery-expert, but not in javascript.. :)

Comment: @Qeremy what does jQuery have to do with the pure-JS code, posted above and with differences in browser behavior?

Comment: You haven't defined `currentNote`

Comment: @yxfxmx can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @yxfxmx; i'm just kidding bud, but be ready to see jquery answers.. :)

Comment: I created a simple jsfiddle and it works (FF24.3ESR).  What happens if you remove all the other logic and just test to see if the event is firing?  
http://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/k2xLbqna/

Answer (score 0):

If it may be helpful for somebody — I've found a solution. The problem lied in CSS. Divs that should trigger event had negative z-index setting in :active state. It turned out that for some reason firefox refuses to trigger events for elements with negative z-index.